# Alternative to LCD monitor for Linux server

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, external-display

I have a linux home server that I use for file storage. I access over the network, usually via SSH. I an LCD monitor that I can hook up to it when I encounter issues with SSH, but I'd like to not have to plugin the monitor just to be able to see the shell.

**Is there a way I can see the video output for the server without having to hook up a monitor?** Is there some way I can "pipe" the video to my laptop?

Alternatively, if there is not a way to "pipe" the video to my laptop, **are there smaller screens out there for things like this? I only need to be able to see 80x24 shell**, so even a tiny LCD should be enough. I've seen some small LCDs for Raspberry Pis, but they look like they would take some work to put together. I'd like something that is just plug and play.

Comment: Could you RDP into it from another machine? Windows RDP or equivalent?  That is how we access Windows servers without needing any monitor on them.

Comment: There are a number of options - e.g: small HDMI field monitors are readily available, a Serial to IP server could work if your system has a serial port that you can dedicate to use for the console.

Comment: Thanks @Attie! I see a lot of reasonable priced field monitors and backup cameras. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can see the video output for the server without having to hook up a monitor?

If you want to run software on the server to accomplish this, there's VNC and NoMachine (NX) and others.

If you don't, and your system has a serial port (or you want to add one with a PCI-E card), you can configure `systemd`/`getty` to provide a login over the serial port.  You can even configure GRUB to work over serial.  This is is probably the most robust way of getting in your computer without a working network.

There are KVM dongles you can buy that will attach to the VGA port and deliver an image through Ethernet or USB.

> are there smaller screens out there for things like this? I only need to be able to see 80x24 shell

A search for "7 inch VGA monitor" turns up some hits.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a VGA to IP encoder supporting ONVIF, with this you would connect the VGA output to the device, and the device to the LAN, then you can connect to the monitor like it was an IP video camera.

They also make versions that accept HDMI and DVI devices if your server is "too new" to have VGA.

What you do NOT want is a VGA to ethernet converter, as those simply allow use of ethernet cables for video transport. You also do not want an ethernet to VGA converter, these operate like a remove VNC viewer to proprietary software running on the computer, and output to a VGA monitor plugged into the device.

Some of these devices can be pretty expensive, I have seen a few around $800. A simple model that does not offer monitor out is much more reasonable, Oupree makes an HDMI input model [OPR-NH100N](https://www.oupree.com/New-H.264-1-Channel-HDMI-Encoder.html) selling for about $180 on ebay, directship from China.

Added bonus you can see video output even before to OS loads, so you know if it rebooted and got stuck at grub or even BIOS.